# GET Request dont save data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm trying to save some data from a GET request. I use StartCoroutine to request and I use Lambda expression for save the data.

My Code is this:

```
  Using UnityEngine;
  using System.Collections;

  public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

 // Use this for initialization
 public void Start () {
     string url1 = "http://localhost/virtualTV/query/?risorsa=";

     string ciao = "http://desktop-pqb3a65:8080/marmotta/resource/ef299b79-35f2-4942-a33b-7e4d7b7cbfb5";
     url1 = url1 + ciao;

     WWW www1 = new WWW(url1);

     var main=new JSONObject(JSONObject.Type.OBJECT);
     var final= new JSONObject(JSONObject.Type.OBJECT);;
     StartCoroutine(firstParsing((value)=>{main = value;
         final= main.Copy();
         Debug.Log(main);
     }));
     Debug.Log(final);
 }

 public IEnumerator firstParsing( System.Action<JSONObject> callback)
 {
     string url2 = "http://localhost/virtualTV/FirstQuery/?risorsa=";
     string ciao = "http://desktop-pqb3a65:8080/marmotta/resource/ef299b79-35f2-4942-a33b-7e4d7b7cbfb5";
     url2 = url2 + ciao;
     WWW www2 = new WWW(url2);
     yield return www2;
     string json = www2.text;

     //Parsing del json con creazione di un array
     var firstjson = new JSONObject(json);
     var tempVideo = new JSONObject(JSONObject.Type.OBJECT);
     var array2 = new JSONObject(JSONObject.Type.OBJECT);

             tempVideo.AddField ("id", firstjson.GetField ("id"));
             tempVideo.AddField ("type", firstjson.GetField ("type"));
             tempVideo.AddField ("url", firstjson.GetField ("url"));
             array2.Add (tempVideo);

     yield return array2;    
     callback (array2);
     Debug.Log ("First Run" + array2);

 }
```

When I try to use FINAL after the command,

```
 final=main.copy()
```

it is empty. Can you help me to save the value in the variable final? Thanks all.

Comment: what is output of `Debug.Log(main);` ?

Comment: It contains the JSON that i want to store in final, it cant copy variable main in variable final, if i print final into StartCoroutine it contains JSON, after that it is empty

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No error , it run perfetcly

Comment: why aren't you assigning it directly from `value` instead of using `Copy`?

Comment: I try to copy because if i use directly , after StartCoroutine(firstParsing((value)=>{main = value; })); , it was empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A coroutine's execution is spread across many frames. When a coroutine encounters a `yield return` statement, it returns to the calling method, which finishes executing, till the task finishes.

---

In your case, the `Debug.Log(final)` statement in `Start` executes as soon as `yield return www2;` in `firstParsing` is executed. The callback hasn't been called yet which is why `final` is empty.

To be able to access the value in `final` after it has been assigned *outside* the callback function, you will have to set a `bool` which is set to `true` after `final` is assigned in the callback. Something like this:

```
StartCoroutine(firstParsing((value)=>{main = value;
    final= main.Copy();
    Debug.Log(main);
    isFinalAssigned = true;
}));

// In another method
if(isFinalAssigned)
{
    // Access final
}
```

You will have to note that the above `if` statement is useful only in a method that is called periodically like `Update`. If you're accessing final in a method that is called only once (like `OnEnable`) you will have to wait for `final` to be assigned. You can use another coroutine for this task like

```
IEnumerator DoSomethingWithFinal()
{
    while(!isFinalAssigned)
       yield return null; // Wait for next frame
    // Do something with final
}
```

The easiest way out is to consume (access) `final` in your `callback`.

EDIT2: From your comments, you can do something like the following. You will **have** to use coroutines, because blocking the main game thread is not a good idea.

```
private JSONObject final = null; // Make final a field
```

Wherever you use `final`, you have two options.

1. Use a null check `if(final == null) return;` This can be impractical.
2. Wait for `final` to be assigned in a coroutine and do something as a callback. This is the only way you can do what you want cleanly.

Look below for the implementation.

```
// Calls callback after final has been assigned
IEnumerator WaitForFinal(System.Action callback) 
{
    while(final == null)
        yield return null; // Wait for next frame
    callback();
}

// This whole method depends on final. 
// This should be similar to your method set up if you have 
// good coding standards (not very long methods, each method does only 1 thing)
void MethodThatUsesFinal()
{
    if (final == null)
    {
        // Waits till final is assigned and calls this method again
        StartCoroutine(WaitForFinal(MethodThatUsesFinal));
        return;
    }

    // use final
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example for the wasiest method to access ad variable final? Becausa i try to use the first method but it never assign the variable final.  thanks a lot

Comment: I use the variable final in the same method that call StartCoroutine

Comment: Is it possible for you to move the code to another method? You can move your accessing code to the callback that you have if you need to access local variables. Can you tell us exactly what you want to do with `final`? The first method I stated won't work in the `Start` method, while the second will.

Comment: I can move code but i need to have the result of my query in variable final after i have call my StartCoroutine function, so i want call StartCoroutine , wait it is finished and using my variable final in the rest of program. StartCoroutine  can call other IEnumerator or other function, but i want wait it finish and have final.

Comment: @user3836982 Check my edited answer. I also suggest that you remove the extra copy (remove `main` and set `final = value`)

Comment: Sorry there was a misunderstanding, i want attend to finish of StartCoroutine , and have complete access to final after //end of start , i am not interesting to access final during the execution of StartCoroutine. Sorry

Comment: @user3836982 check my latest edit. That'll be the only way you can do what you want cleanly.